# derby.js vs capsule/thoonk?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript

Have you use either of these setups?

I'm looking for general pros and cons - Thanks!!

http://derbyjs.com/

vs

http://andyet.net/blog/2011/nov/16/backbonejs-and-capsule-and-thoonk-oh-my-a-scalable/

https://github.com/andyet/capsule

https://github.com/andyet/thoonk.js

Answer (score 2):

I started with capsule/thoonk and then later switched to derby when I saw that capsule/thoonk isn't actively developed anymore.

As far as I know, derby is even made by the same people.

So I'd strongly suggest you use derby.

Comment: derby isn't made by the same people.

Comment: Derby not by the same people, but by the authors of everyauth & mongoose-auth.  Capsule & thoonk are dead, but the real competitor to derby now is socketstream.  I prefer derby, but socketstream is much more popular.

Comment: Howdy, I wrote Capsule and work with Fritzy/Lance who wrote Thoonk. Thoonk isn't dead, it's being worked on in the scripting branch for 2.6 and is being actively used in production by disqus and others. But comparing thoonk to derby/socketstream isn't apples to apples. Thoonk is a data handling layer, the others are full web stacks. Capsule is a series of helpers for backbone and will likely be re-incarnated in a different form to work with changes in how we're architecting AndBang 2.0.

Comment: In addition, unless they've come a long way since I last saw them, neither derby or socketstream are really production ready (I'd love to be proven wrong). If you want to build secure, production realtime app, I'd suggest you learn how to script redis :)